# Download an HTML file so that it opens in an email client (e.g. MS Outlook)

Tags: html, email, outlook, mime-types

I'm struggling to find an answer to what I thought would be a relatively straightforward problem, and wondered if anyone could help:

It is to find a way of allowing users to open downloaded HTML files in an email client such as MS Outlook (without having to save them first).

We have a Web-based application that allows users to upload files, including emails. To do this, they need to save the email onto their network, and then upload the saved file via the browser's 'file select' control. The files are saved in an Oracle database, and we have a utility that allows the user to later download the saved email. When they do so, they are given the option to 'Open' or 'Save'.

When the email was saved using the .msg format, opening the downloaded email opens that email in Outlook, and all the usual email functionality is available. However, if the email is saved in HTML, selecting 'open' always loads the email content into the browser.

Is there a way of invoking Outlook when the user opens an HTML file from the Web app, so that they don't have to either 1) always save their emails as .msg files or 2) download the email to the network and use 'open with' to open it in Outlook?

The download utility allows us to set the MIME type, but application/vnd.ms-outlook (and the various email-related types) have no effect; so that an HTML email always opens in the browser.

We have also tried changing the filename extension to '.msg', but this results in an Outlook error message and the email does not open. Removing the file extension altogether means that the file still opens in the browser.

Changing the HTM/HTML file associations so that they open with Outlook is not an option for us, I'm afraid.

Does anyone know of a solution to this? Although the problem as I've described it isn't such a big deal for our users, we were hoping to generate draft emails programmatically for users to edit and send, but without the ability to open an HTML file in Outlook, this is going to be a lot trickier than we'd hoped.

Our main network browser is still IE7, incidentally.

Many thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook does not handle HTML files at all. It needs to either be MSG or EML file.

For the latter option, it is easy enough to create a dummy EML file with an HTML MIME part that represents your HTML data.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry - It looks like it's all in the file associations (as Greg also suggests).

Comment: MSG file format is an binary as it gets. EML (MIME) is text. The end result looks the same to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

The file extension would have to be set to .msg, and the file would have to be rewritten in this format as well. You can see the technical specifications for this format here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, and there are conversion utilities available as well.